# How to position item of ListView?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a ListView with number of items. I'd like to place the item being clicked in the top of the screen. i am trying to use **requestChildRectangleOnScreen** of **ListView** that seems to do the job, however I cannot figure out how to properly specify the rectangle param. Any suggestion and/or code sample will be really helpful

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you need to create your own rectangle with this constructor : Rect(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) and then pass it to your method

Comment: Yes, you're right. The question is what values I should use to init the rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the rectangle of the view with getLeft() aso.

```
rectangle = new Rect(editText.getLeft(), editText.getTop(), editText.getRight(), editText.getBottom());
```